# How Lucene will suit my need?

Tags: lucene

I am having a huge XML file with multiple documents in it (This can be easily converted to multiple files per document, if required). The file size of this huge XML is around 4 GB. I need to index it for better and faster search for the users. Also I am using XSLT to transform this data.

Below is my basic XML structure-

```
<Docs>
  <Doc>
    <Title t=""></Title>
    <Desc></Desc>
    <Info></Info>
  </Doc>
  <Doc>
    <Title t=""></Title>
    <Desc></Desc>
    <Info></Info>
  </Doc>
</Docs>
```

Each `Doc` can be separated, if required. If the user searched for specific word(s), I will be displaying the complete document in HTML format using XSLT.

As I have not used Lucene so far, I have certains questions -

1. Will I have to keep both XML file and Lucene Index file?
2. If only later one, then, will it be transformable through XSLT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, you would keep your XML file on-disk.

Then on application start-up, you'd process the file to create a Lucene Index.

You could have a function to add/remove things from the index, to save the 'expensive' task of reprocessing the entire XML file on-change.

Once your data is indexed you can give Lucene a query.

The returned result could be XML and then you could use XSLT handle the View.

-

The above is a very high level, 'yes' you can answer.

In reality, I've done a similar thing where Umbraco content that is stored in a database, is analysed and then populated into a Lucene index (adding additional fields to make searching easier).

We then wrote a XSLT extension, that allowed a RAW lucene query to be passed to some C# that then returns the result set as in-memory XML.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="$result-set/result" />

<xsl:template match="result">
<article>
  <h1><xsl:value-of select="title" /></h1>
</article>
</xsl:template>
```

There's some great ideas in this article. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-lucene/

Answer (score 0):

I would say don't save raw XML in Lucene index. Save the values of XML tags and attributes as fields for a Lucene document.
You can save the path of the resulted HTML (the output of XSLT transformation) as part of ***Doc*** in Lucene as a field. This is done before/after indexing.

So when you found a document, you don't have to build the HTML view during runtime. You will only use the path to the right HTML representation.